# Restrict UIViewcontroller orientation and orientation free of same viewcontroller subviews

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, orientation, landscape-portrait

I have one requirement,

**Expected Hierarchy:**

```
UIviewcontroller (Portrait mode)
    - cameraView    (Portrait mode)
        -uiview (Portrait mode)
            - Scrollview (DMLazyScrollview library) (Landscape) 
                - viewcontroller(Landscape)
                    - Imageview (Landscape)
```

I am developing camera application. I have one requirement that I need lock the **UIViewcontroller** in **portrait mode** for **camera** and as per the device rotation see the above hierarchy. (Check iPhone **Default Camera** application lock the orientation from **access control**). Launch the **iOS camera application and see the top buttons.** I achieved this but facing the problem in resizing the subviews.

The problem is, if I transform the scrollview it is not fitting into the screen as per the rotation and the subviews are also not resizing properly.

Please correct me if I am wrong for the following questions.

1. Is it possible to launch the subviews opposite of its superview orientation?
2. Is it possible to resize the subviews of scrollview to imageview as per above hierarchy without and transform.
3. With transform how to resize the subviews and scrollview?

If possible , Please share sample code, links and possible ways.

Thanks in advance.

**Step to understand the flow and problem:**

1. [image: Default]

2.

[image: Default camera]

3. My application in portrait mode

[image]

4. Problem of my application
   **Red border - Scrollview and uiview**

   **Green border - Imageview inside the uiview**

[image]